# Como eu faço referencia ao Entity Framework 6 apartir do .Net Core Class Library?

Tags: entity-framework, ddd, .net-core

Ao instalar pelo Nuget o Entity Framework obtive o seguinte erro em sua referencia:

> The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.6

Como contornar este erro? Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei grata!

Comment: Tem que instalar a versão [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/)

Comment: Eu pesquisei mais um pouco e achei [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6). O que acabou resolvendo meu problema. Thanks @VirgilioNovic!

Answer (score 1):

O EntityFramework 6 não é suportado no .NET Core. Para o .NET Core você precisa utilizar o [Entity Framework Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/). Você pode sim usar o EF6 com projetos feitos utilizando [VS2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/whatsnew/) ou [.NET Core Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), porém referenciando o full framework no .csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```